# How do I put a block in a form?

Tags: forms, blocks

How do I put a block in a form?

My searches on this site and on google only have lead to questions of putting a form in a block. I want the opposite. I have a form definition array in a module, and I want to add in an existing block.

Comment: It would be difficult. In Drupal you only put blocks in regions, and regions are theme-dependent. Forms are module-dependent so it will be a lot of ugly hacks to do it that way. Do you have any actual problem you are facing, any use case that would require it?

Comment: I have the form I want, except it's in a block. Instead of duplicating the code defining the form in another form, I would just like to put it right where I want it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  $block = module_invoke('module_name', 'block_view', 'block_id');

  $form['block'] = array(
    '#markup' => render($block),
  );
```

Comment: Of course if form itself will end up in this block, it will cause beautiful case of WSOD.

Comment: It's working out for me.